# generate vector of difference in days from pandas dates column

Tags: python, pandas, date

Have pandas dataframe, read in from tab-sep file, containing single date column (pd.read_table given the argument 'parse_dates = ['dates'] so that this column is a datetime64 Dtype, as revealed by mydf.info().)

I need a vector of the successive days diffs; i.e., the second date - the first, the third - the second, etc. The vector of course will have a length of one less than the len of the column of dates itself.

Coming from R, it's dirt simple in that environment, but beginning to think I'll hit the end of my natural lifetime before getting the "how to accomplish same" answer in Pandaland.

Comment: `day_diffs = mydf['dates'].diff().dt.days` The resulting vector will have a length of one less than the length of the original column of dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `diff` to compute the difference between the current row and the previous one. With `pd.DatetimeIndex`, you obtain a `pd.TimedeltaIndex`. You have to drop the first values (NaN) to get a vector with one less element.

```
>>> df['dates'].diff().dropna().dt.days.to_numpy()
array([8, 4, 7, 3, 2, 1], dtype=int32)

>>> df
       dates
0 2023-01-05
1 2023-01-13
2 2023-01-17
3 2023-01-24
4 2023-01-27
5 2023-01-29
6 2023-01-30
```